# What is the equivalent javascript closure in c#?

Tags: javascript, c#, function, delegates, closures

Consider this simple .js code:

```
const createCounter = () => {
    let value = 0;
    return {
        increment: () => { value += 1 },
        decrement: () => { value -= 1 },
        logValue: () => { console.log(value); }
    }
}
```

// Usage

```
const { increment, decrement, logValue } = createCounter();
```

I'm pretty sure c# support first class function, note that I don't want to use classes to remake the code above. What is the equivalent closure in c#?

I have made this:

```
public Func<WhatType?> CreateCounter = () => {
    var value = 0;
    return what?
}
```

Comment: You could use a `Map` of functions. I don't know if there's such a thing as destructuring in C# (or similar)

Comment: could you provide any examples or references to Map of functions which will hold the value state?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could use a mix of [ValueTuples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.valuetuple?view=netframework-4.8) and [lambda expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/lambda-expressions).

```cs
private static (Action increment, Action decrement, Action logValue) CreateCounter()
{
    var value = 0;

    return
        (
            () => value += 1,
            () => value -= 1,
            () => Console.WriteLine(value)
        );
}
```

Usage

```cs
var (increment, decrement, logValue) = CreateCounter();
increment();
increment();
decrement();
logValue();
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the following code using `Dictionary` to Map `enumerated data types` with an `Action Delegate`

```
void Main()
{
    OperationActionDictionary[Operation.Increment](); // Execute Increment
    OperationActionDictionary[Operation.Increment](); // Execute Increment
    OperationActionDictionary[Operation.Decrement](); // Execute Decrement
    OperationActionDictionary[Operation.LogValue]();  // Execute LogValue
}

public enum Operation
{
    Increment,
    Decrement,
    LogValue
}

public static int Value = 0;

public Dictionary<Operation,Action> OperationActionDictionary = new Dictionary<Operation, Action>
{
    [Operation.Increment] = () => Value += 1,
    [Operation.Decrement] = () => Value -= 1,
    [Operation.LogValue] = () => Console.WriteLine($"Value :: {Value}")
};
```

Only catch here or in any other code for modifying a shared `Value` object would be in case it is Multi thread access, then you need to take care of thread safety in this case using `Interlocked.Increment` or `Interlocked.Decrement`